# WSO2 EI Rest Api - Implement Custom handler class

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

When i try to add Handler class into my Rest API
it works after it was compiled

when i need to edit it **Handler class** statement is disappeared 
But it is worked inside

***What is the problem?***

[image]

It is creating handler class and save it successfully
After this when i click again edit api, its gone

[image]

Comment: Don't you see any errors in the log file? a deployment failure?

Comment: there is no error it works fine

Comment: this usually happens when you have a syntax error in the config. when that happens the config is reverted to a working state removing the incorrect part. but there should be an error log.

Comment: Sometimes this can be a rendering issue. The handler definition is not rendered properly in the source view. Could you check the API config file (EI_HOME/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/apis)? Can you see the handler definition?

Comment: (EI_HOME/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/apis)
I opened api's xml file in notepad ++, handler class is there, it does not appear only source view(Management Console)

Comment: Hi. I have same problem. could you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

In EI AFAIR, this wasn't supported in UI rendering view however if its saved it will work properly. Also you might use the Integration Studio to create the API, then there won't be such issues.

Comment: Thank you sir, i will try this

Answer (score 0):

It is not shown in management console source or design view, but if you view in folders like:

```
EI-Home/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/apis/your API
```

…the handler is present in code.